# "GetAllDocumentsByKey" Can not get all document by key

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

My problem is when use `GetAllDocumentByKey` for get all document that's contain "keys" is multiple keys but the result from use below code can't get all
such as sometimes is returned only 2 document, but it's should return 5 document  that's contains that's keys.

How should I solve this problem?

```
   Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim view As NotesView
    Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection
    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim keys( 0 To 1 ) As Variant
    'Dim vc As NotesViewEntryCollection



    Dim defect As Variant
    defect = uidoc.FieldGetText("DefectMode")
    keys( 0 ) =defect
    Dim PartNo As Variant
    partNo = uidoc.FieldGetText("PartNo")
    keys( 1 ) = partNo

    Set view = db.GetView("EmbedView2" )
    Set dc = view.GetAllDocumentsByKey(keys,False)
    'Set vc=db.GetView("EmbedView2")

    Call dc.PutAllInFolder("EmbedFolder")
    Call workspace.DialogBox( "Embedded form", True, True, True, True, False, False, "Select Part No",,True,True )

    'Call dc.RemoveAllFromFolder( "EmbedFolder" )

End Sub
```

Comment: Does your application use ReaderName or AuthorName fields?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz No, I'm not . I just only get value from normal fields. thank you for your question.

Comment: I'm not asking about what fields you are getting values from. I am asking whether anything in the entire application uses ReaderName or AuthorName fields. I'm asking because if such fields are being used, that will hide some documents from you, so your code will not be able to get them.

Comment: GetAllDocumentsByKey with an array of keys gets a collection of documents from a view with multiple sorted columns and finds the documents where the first N columns match the keys in the array of N elements. Check your view to make sure the first two columns that are sorted contain the "DefectMode" and "PartNo" in that order.

Comment: Is it possible, the values of DefectMode and PartNo are multivalue in documents? If so, GetAllDocumentsByKey returns only first occurence of such document in the view index.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to proceed each keys value separately ?

```
Set view = db.GetView("EmbedView2" )
ForAll key in keys
  Set dc = view.GetAllDocumentsByKey(key,False)
  Call dc.PutAllInFolder("EmbedFolder")
end ForAll
```

[Edit] In order to understand where is the problem, check if your keys really return data. See the output for each key.

```
Set view = db.GetView("EmbedView2" )
ForAll key in keys
  Set dc = view.GetAllDocumentsByKey(key,False)
  print "*** for " + key + " number or matching: " & dc.Count 
  Call dc.PutAllInFolder("EmbedFolder")
end ForAll
```

Comment: I try your code above but still can't get all document in that's view. The result still same my original code. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: see my edit, I suspect you have a problem with the key value

Comment: About check number of key too, I have use dc.count in my code for check a number of document that's return  but that's less than in document that's should return . This is my problem . thank you for your suggestion .

Comment: I think this is incorrect advice. GetAllDocumentsByKey with an array of keys gets a collection of documents from a view with multiple sorted columns and finds the documents where the first N columns match the keys in the array of N elements. So your testing will (or should) only find results for the first key in the array.